# Uniformly lighting model in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3D model which I want to be lit uniformly from all directions without any shadows. Currently I am using a Spotlight, but since it is directional, I can see only some part of the model lit at any point of time.

One approach to solve this problem is to have a spotlight at each corner of the bounding box pointing towards the center of the bounding box. This way I will have 8 spotlights.

Is this the standard approach to solve this problem, or will this approach also have limitations ? Can you suggest a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to generate fairly uniform lighting in three.js.

If you want a spotlight or directional light, be sure to add some ambient light:

```
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
```

If you do so, also set `material.ambient` to match `material.color`, so the un-lit sides of your model will look right. (`material.ambient` is being removed in r.71).

A second solution is to use a hemisphere light.

A third solution, since you don't care about shadows, is to add a point light as a child of the camera.

```
scene.add( camera ); // required only if the camera has children

camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 ) );
```

In this way, the scene will be nicely lit, regardless of the view direction.

three.js r.70